# Webrtc on centos7 gives GLIBC_2.18 not found

Tags: webrtc, chromium, glibc, ninja

I am trying to build webrtc on CentOS7. I was able to install all the webrtc required dependency I am facing an issue where gn(meta-build system that generate Ninja Files) complains that it cannot find `GLIBC_2.18`. I am following the build instructions from here (https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/) and getting this error on [generating ninja build files stage](https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/#generating-ninja-project-files).

Stacktrace of the Error:

```
$ gn gen out/debug-x64 "--args=enable_iterator_debugging=false is_component_build=false"

webrtc-checkout/src/buildtools/linux64/gn: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by webrtc-checkout/src/buildtools/linux64/gn)
```

Any pointers on how I can resolve this without upgrading the glibc version. I did a grep on libc.so.6 to find the glibc versions supported :

```
$ strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.15
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.17
```

Answer (score 1):

> `webrtc-checkout/src/buildtools/linux64/gn: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.18' not found`

This error means that `gn` has been built on a `GLIBC-2.18` (or later) system, and *requires* `GLIBC-2.18` to run.

> Any pointers on how I can resolve this without upgrading the glibc version

You can build `gn` from source on your system.

Alternatively, you may be able to install `glibc-2.18` or above as a second glibc, without upgrading the "main" glibc. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) provides details.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a bug in chromium buildtools which was resolved (https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/buildtools/+/595110). I was able to update and it fixed my issue.